# How to set up path in form for inner models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

Here's the structure of models in `routes.rb`:

```
  resources :model_a do
    resources :model_b do
      resources :model_c do
        resources :photos do
          collection do
            get :upload_data
          end
        end
      ...
    ...
  ...
```

On the URL

```
http://localhost:3001/model_a/1/model_b/2/model_c/3/photos/upload_data
```

is displayed form for choosing files. It's in the controller called `Photos` and the action `upload_data`.

I am getting the error message

> undefined method `photos_path' for #<#:...>

I think it's because of this controller is inside another ones, but how to fix it?

Comment: can you post your `rake routes`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, it is wise to heed the warning in the [Rails Doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)

> Resources should never be nested more than 1 level deep.

This is a guideline based on the experience that deeply nested resources cause unneeded complexity.

The error you are describing sounds like it is due to using the incorrect path helper in your view form. Since it is nested, it is not `photos_path`, but a combination of all of the nested resources to some monstrosity like:

```
model_a_model_b_model_c_upload_data_photos_path(model_a, model_b, model_c)
```

You should check your `rake routes` for the correct and unwieldy route to use for the path.

Answer (score 0):

May be this may resolve your problem : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Here there is a note that : `"Resources should never be nested more than 1 level deep."`

As you have mentioned the code , you have used more than 1 level. I don't think its a good practice.

Hope this would help you.